# QML - Shape Type, Property data has no method for removing Entries?

Tags: qt, qml

For my application I am creating some dynamic lines to show them on screen.
I got tried creating the lines as in this example from the qt documentation:

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qtquick-shapes-content-interactive-qml.html

In this example the shapepath is added into the data property of shape via:

shape.data.push(p);

However I want to remove something from this list but neither pop() or splice work. Is there a way to remove items from the data list property of Shape?

In the qt doc, not even the push method was actually mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` property in `Shape` is not a JS array and is quite limited.

According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12//qml-list.html):

> Note that objects cannot be individually added to or removed from the list once created; to modify the contents of a list, it must be reassigned to a new list.

So, you have to create a new list without the item you want to remove:

```
function removeFromShapeAt(index) {
            var d = []
            for (var i = 0; i !== shape.data.length; ++i) {
                if (i !== index) {
                    d.push(shape.data[i])
                }
            }
            shape.data = d
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This cleared up a lot of my confusion!

Comment: How do you clear the array? Setting it to `[]` does not delete the path elements for me